# running executable files from system command

Tags: command, system

I'm able to execute the same file manually, bot not using system command. 
ex. system("./update.cgi uImage\n"); 
Here update.cgi is the executable and uImage is a file i'm passing as an argument to update.cgi, have taken care of all permissions.

Could any1 tell me why it is not executing from system command.

Comment: I assume this is on a Unix-like system. Did you check the return value of system() and/or errno?

Comment: Also: are you sure the working directory of your process is the one that contains update.cgi?